# How to keep Entity Tags (Etags) generated by PHP

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, plesk

I'm running a small RESTfull api server from a hosted Plesk Obsidian server. A small PHP based REST Api generates ETags for resources and are correct on our development environment. In production we have rely on a hosted Plesk Obsidian based solution. Whatever we try ETags generated in PHP never arrive at the client. I've been through hoster support but they seem unable to solve this.

How can we make sure `ETag`s generated by PHP will arrive at clients? What do I need to tell hoster support to make this happen?

The code to generate the ETag is a simple md5 of the resource provided:

```php
header( 'ETag: ' . md5($payload) );
```

The ETag disappears from the response on production.